# not able to get json back to jsp from servlet in ajax code

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

I am new to `Ajax`, `Jquery`, `JSON` stuff. I have created one login page in `jsp` `servlet` technology. On login page, when user presses submit button, data gets collected in `JSON` and transferred to controller through `AJAX`. Now, in controller if on some condition, login name found to be correct, then it should use `RequestDispatcher` to dispatch it to success page. However if condition not satisfied, then it should write the message in JSON object and return it as content type `json`. Now the problem is that I am able receive `JSON` data on controller, but not able to redirect on success and also not able to show alert box to user if he entered wrong data. Below are the files:

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function validateAndSet()
{
    var jsonRequest = {};
    var login_name = $.trim($('#loginName').val());
    var password = $.trim($('#password').val());
    if(login_name=='' || login_name.length==0 ){
        alert("Please enter login name.");
        $('#loginName').focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(password=='' || password.length==0 ){
        alert("Please enter password.");
        $('#password').focus();
        return false;
    }
    jsonRequest["login_name"] = login_name;
    jsonRequest["password"] = password;
    return jsonRequest;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="commonResources/Header.jsp">
<jsp:param value="none" name="headerMenu"/>
</jsp:include>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#but").click(function(){
         var formData=validateAndSet();
         var strUrl="rwcntrlr.do?action=loginForm";
         $.post(strUrl, {jsonData: JSON.stringify(formData)},function(response){
                response = jQuery.parseJSON( response);
                if(response.status=='NOT OK')
                {
                    alert("not ok");
                }
                else{
                    alert('OK');
                }
            });
    }); 
});
</script>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="p1">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Login</h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <center>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td height="50">LoginName:</td><td height="50"><input type="text" id="loginName" name="loginName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="20">Password:</td><td height="20"><input type="password" id="password" name="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height="50" colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" id="but" name="subBut" value="Go>" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

controller servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String formName=request.getParameter("action");

        if(formName.equalsIgnoreCase("loginForm")){
            String strJSONData = request.getParameter("jsonData");
            System.out.println(strJSONData);// data received correctly...
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();

            try{
                JSONObject requestedJSONObject = new JSONObject(strJSONData);
                String login_name = requestedJSONObject.getString("login_name");
                String password = requestedJSONObject.getString("password");
                if(login_name.equalsIgnoreCase("u2")){
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("employeeSection/employeeDailySheet.jsp");
                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                    }
                    else{
                        jsonResponse.put("status", "NOT OK");
                        response.setContentType("application/json");
                        response.getWriter().write(jsonResponse.toString());
                    }

            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
    }
```

When I presses submit button on login.jsp, nothing happens. No console error is shown. What should I do to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you using Spring your controller mapping annotation is missing.
From html/jsp you are redirecting to some url but in your controller same url is not mapped.

Comment: no i am not using spring, anyway controller mapping is correct because it is receiving data on controller